# How to pinpoint source of Firefox window behavior

Tags: firefox

One of my favorite Unity features is the ability to pin windows to one side of the screen or the other. My tendency to do this a lot has made me notice a bug where when I'm moving a Firefox window I get the clenched fist and even after letting go of the window the pointer never returns to normal. After this I'm unable to use the mouse normally until I do a `killall firefox` from the terminal.

How do I pinpoint the source of this error since I cannot reliably reproduce it, and I'm not sure of all of the systems that might be involved?

Firefox 13.01 seen on both Ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds very much like the one I reported on [bugzilla gnome here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679355)

I believe it is a bug in GTK. If you are able to, try to reproduce the steps on that page using Gedit. If you get the same results, then we can report this and hopefully get it resolved sooner.

Comment: That report definitely describes the same behavior I'm seeing, but unfortunately I can't reproduce that one in gedit.